# The table 'catalog_product_index_price_tmp' is full error

Tags: product, magento-enterprise, configurable-product, save, enterprise-1.14

I faced one strange issue with product saving on Magento EE 1.14.2.4. This issue appears only when I save exactly one product, I'm able to save other products without any problems. Here is screenshot of issue:
[image: sqlstate error]

Do you have any ideas why it appears?

Answer (score 3):

The error says the table is full. Have you got enough disk space on the server?

Alternatively, you might want to look at your mySQL value for "max_heap_table_size" and increase the value.

Comment: The disk space is enough, I got this error because of size limit of `catalog_product_index_price_tmp` table. When I truncated table `catalog_product_index_price` it fixed the error. Seems some index related issue. For some reason magento filled the table.

Comment: Aha. Glad you managed to find the cause of it :)

Answer (score 0):

I also had this error when trying to save a product. In my case, the error message "General error: 1114 The table 'catalog_product_index_price_tmp' is full" was misleading. I tried a bunch of different solution to try to increase disk space and memory but they did not work.

It turned out that my issue was that I had recently updated my local development database with new product data from my production database, but I had forgotten to run the indexer. Running it solved my issue:

```
php /path_to_magento_base_dir/shell/indexer.php reindexall
```