# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1114 The table 'catalog_product_index_price_tmp' is full

Tags: configurable-product, magento-2.1

While changing the configurable product status , getting a strange error like The table 'catalog_product_index_price_tmp' is full,
[image]

Comment: See also: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/135203/the-table-catalog-product-index-price-tmp-is-full-error

Comment: 1. maybe your disk is full?
2. try to truncate the table manually and try again

Answer (score 0):

It Looks like have excited the OS limits on file size or you are out of storage

> If a table-full error occurs, it may be that the disk is full or that
>   the table has reached its maximum size. The effective maximum table
>   size for MySQL databases is usually determined by operating system
>   constraints on file sizes, not by MySQL internal limits.

Answer (score 0):

First check **tmp_table_size** & **max_heap_table_size** in MYSQL server

1. => SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'tmp_table_size'
2. => SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_heap_table_size'

If size is 16M ,**Increase Table Size upto 512M/128M/..**.

3. => SET GLOBAL tmp_table_size = 1024 * 1024 * 512
4. => SET GLOBAL max_heap_table_size = 1024 * 1024 * 512

it solved that problem.